# How to consume Monit Web Service API java

Tags: java, rest, monit

I'm trying to connect with monit web service api (Restful Services), using the following code:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://localhost:2812/z_security_check");

NameValuePair[] credentials = {
                new BasicNameValuePair("z_username", "admin"),
                new BasicNameValuePair("z_password", "monit"),
                new BasicNameValuePair("z_csrf_protection", "off")
        };

 List<NameValuePair> body = Arrays.asList(credentials);

 httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(body));
 HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);

 System.out.println("Post parameters : " + httpPost.getEntity().getContent());
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

 BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

 StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
 String line = "";
 while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(line);
 }

 System.out.println(result.toString());
```

But always I have the same answer:

```
Post parameters : java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@79d0569b
Response Code : 401
<html><head><title>401 Unauthorized</title></head><body bgcolor=#FFFFFF><h2>Unauthorized</h2>You are not authorized to access monit. Either you supplied the wrong credentials (e.g. bad password), or your browser doesn't understand how to supply the credentials required<hr><a href='http://mmonit.com/monit/'><font size=-1>monit 5.14</font></a></body></html>

Process finished with exit code 0
```

but when I enter via browser (http: // localhost: 2812 /) asked me the credentials and displays the information correctly

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the web service of monit is available only in the paid version M/Monit, I solve it by making a Web Scraping with jsup of the main page and got the necessary data